# WPF 3D Perspective camera question

Tags: wpf, 3d, camera, flip, perspective

I am working on a 3D flip control that can flip horizontally, vertically and can have any size and square or rectangular shape.

While I have it working, I ran into a very odd issue with the perspective camera.  When I create a MeshGeometry3D I scale to the proper ratio of the content.  If the width > height, all is well.  However, if height > width, then the 3d mesh is sized too small.

The only thing that fixed this was (if height > width) change the UpDirection on the perspective camera from 0 1 0 to 1 0 0 and apply a 90 rotate transform.  When I do this, everything looks perfect.

Anyone know why this is?  Does the perspective camera only take width into account when sizing the mesh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with the `FieldOfView` property. That's the angle at which the scene is "seen" by the camera. In your case multiplying the ratio by `height / width` without changing the FoV should suffice.

Comment: Gave it a shot, but couldnt figure out what the proper angle is- if default angle is 90, and height is 400, width 200 then I thing the angle should be about 57 (using some very rusty trigonometry!).  But the mesh is not quite exact... ?